# Flask socketio setup

Tags: python, flask, websocket, socket.io

I just finished adding these changes to my server:

https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

When I try to connect (to port 5000 I suppose => var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000'); I get a connection refused error.

My question: where can I specify socketio on which port to listen? I can't find any indications of how to do this. I also searched the added JS file for any port numbers, but couldn't find any.

Comment: `io.connect('http://localhost:5000')` does specify the port. It's port 5000.

Comment: @nathancahill I meant on the serverside. I want to specify the port to listen to since 5000 is already in use by flask.

Comment: Are you still using `app.run()`? You need to start your server with `socketio.run(app)` instead. If that's not the problem, please update your post with some code.